# VMWare ESX Datastore Usage Monitoring and Alerting

Tags: vmware-esx, storage-area-network, alerts, sms

I am trying to find the easiest way to receive alerts on datastore usage for my ESX 4.1 hosts.  I have virtual center.  My hosts are connected to Equallogic SAN's, and I would like to somehow get, at a minimum, free space on each LUN into SolarWinds Orion NPM 10.1 so that I can dispatch email and SMS alerts.

I have not been having much luck thus far finding a solution, which includes SolarWind's own storage monitoring utility.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version are you using and do you have vCenter?

Comment: I have virtual center, yes, and the hosts are on version 4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chopper got it right -

In VCenter, go to the Alarms tab, then click on definitions.  Double click the entry called:

"Datacenter Usage on disk"

On the Actions tab, click Add, and a new action will be created.  Hit the drop down for the new action, and change it to "send a notification trap".

Comes in handy, if you don't have any other monitoring solution, or in your case, are having problems with the current one.

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance, that seems to have been the ticket :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answers to my questions - given you have VC already I'd be tempted to let it manage your actual datastores and just point any snmp alerts at your own escalation boxes - this way you'll get more than just the datastore issues too.